# Bootstrap - Vertically Align Button With Well

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a well and I am trying to vertically align a button on the right of it. I guess I could just use traditional CSS, but I'd rather not run the risk of breaking the bootstrap.

```html
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='row well top-buffer'>
      <div class='col-md-10'>
        <a href='#' id='dl'>v0.0.1 - July 11, 2015 | 20:15:34</a>
        <p>Note: This beta is only available until<br>August 8, 2015 at 11:59PM PST</p>
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-2 vcenter'>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right">Download</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yvu4xg3w/)

Comment: The button is already aligned to the right. The Bootstrap "pull-right" class takes care of it. Check this out => http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNMbPa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you have to use col-xs class to make it possible have a look on js fillde i have created for you :  `https://jsfiddle.net/2w4Lc5L7/`
```

Comment: Interesting. It looks like I just had to add the margin to the CSS for vcenter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the pull-right class to the div instead of the button.

```
    <div class="col-md-2 vcenter pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn- lg">Download</button>
    </div>
```