# Vertically middle align button in bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to vertically middle align the buttons in bootstrap columns.

**Fiddler:** https://jsfiddle.net/ebwwvy6m/23/

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-3 vcenter">                   
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="BtnExport">Export</button>
    </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            Comment
                            <textarea rows="2" class="form-control" id="TextAreaComment"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 vcenter">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="BtnEntry">Abandon</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.vcenter {
    display:inline-block !important;
    vertical-align:middle !important;   
}
```

**Expectation:**

[image]

**What I tried?**

I tried following the solutions provided here,

1. [Vertical align button in the middle of the column- bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232114/vertical-align-button-in-the-middle-of-the-column-bootstrap)
2. [Vertical align button middle next to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36937888/vertical-align-button-middle-next-to-text)
3. [Bootstrap - Vertically Align Button With Well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283584/bootstrap-vertically-align-button-with-well)

But, I am not getting the solution. Any suggestion will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use flexbox, just use the snippet on parent of the button in which you want to center the item.

(in your case .row div)

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/xsmnnLoc/

But this method doesn't work on IE 10 and lower

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. +1 from me. I will wait for any other suggestion that works in IE 9 and above.

Answer (score 35):

`.align-self-center` will work.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 align-self-center">

</div>
```